# Wrong OnClick Message on Page Load

Tags: javascript, css, function, buttonclick

I've implemented an **onclick function** to Hide a Page section on Page load. Then there will be a button that says "Show More".

And when this button is clicked, it should show the Hidden section, and the button should say "Show Less".

Unfortunately, when my Page loads, the section that's supposed to be hidden is not hidden, and the button still says "Show More".

This is the wrong flow. The section should be hidden on Page load.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you link to some codepen or jsfiddle where we can test your code?

Comment: A resonable start as @SwapnilSoni mentioned would be a code snippet. How are you hiding your element? In my opinion the easiest way would probably be to use CSS and set the element to display: none by default, and then control that CSS attribute with javascript to toggle the section on and off.

Comment: Here's my HTML
<button id="ShowMore" onclick="toggleBlock()">Show More</button>

And here's the JS
function toggleBlock() {
  var myBlock = document.getElementById("service-area2");

  var blockButton = document.getElementById("ShowMore");

  if (myBlock.hidden) {
    blockButton.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    myBlock.hidden = false;
  } else {
    blockButton.innerHTML = "Show More";
    myBlock.hidden = true;
  }
}

CODEPEN LINK: https://codepen.io/Gamip/pen/OJjoXoP

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

### HTML

```
<button id="ShowMore" onclick="toggleBlock()">Show More</button>

<div id="service-area2">Content</div>
```

### CSS

```
#service-area2 {
  display: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
function toggleBlock() {
  const myBlock = document.getElementById("service-area2");
  const blockButton = document.getElementById("ShowMore");
  
  const isMyBlockVisible = myBlock.style.display === "block";
  
  myBlock.style.display = isMyBlockVisible ? "none" : "block";
  blockButton.textContent = isMyBlockVisible ? "Show More" : "Show Less";
}
```

I have created a jsFiddle to see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0t3jnsq4/).